# Archlinux intelgraphic + 2 монитора = зависание при загрузке

Tags: archlinux, xorg

IntelCore i5-6600
В параметрах ядра прописан параметр `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1` для новых процессоров. Когда подключен один монитор, то всё нормально, но когда подключаю второй монитор получаю зависание системы в момент перехода на экран логина.
Подскажите, куда копать. Гугление толку не дало.